# How to Explicitly terminate OkHttpDownloader instance

Tags: java, android, picasso, java-io, okhttp

I'm using Picasso, so I tried to manage catching using OkHTTP, after setting strick mode, I'm now getting "**A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released**" error.

Here's what's in the Application Class.

```
@Override
   public void onCreate() {
      boolean DEVELOPER_MODE = true;
      if (DEVELOPER_MODE) {
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                            .detectDiskReads()
                            .detectDiskWrites()
                            .detectNetwork()
                            .penaltyLog()
                            .build());

         StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                            .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
                            .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                            .penaltyLog()
                            .penaltyDeath()
                            .build());
      }

      super.onCreate();
      MultiDex.install(this);
      Picasso.Builder  b          = new Picasso.Builder(this);
      OkHttpDownloader downloader = new OkHttpDownloader(this, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
      b.downloader(downloader);
      Picasso built = b.build();
      built.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
      built.setLoggingEnabled(true);
      Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);
   }
```

I seems the problem is with `new OkHttpDownloader(this, Integer.MAX_VALUE);`

How do I end this?

**Here's the error :**

```
 A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released.
See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.

java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called                                                                       
at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:180)                                                                       
at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:82)                                                                      
at com.android.okhttp.okio.GzipSource.<init>(GzipSource.java:62)                                                                    
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.unzip(HttpEngine.java:645)                                                                     
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:827)                                                     
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:439)                                                                   
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl
```